# sphinx autodoc creates blank page on readthedocs, but correctly includes module docstring locally

Tags: python-sphinx, read-the-docs, autodoc

I'm getting different results from autodoc when I run sphinx locally (versions 1.6.6 or 2.0.1 on Anaconda Python 3.6.8 for Mac) than when I run it on readthedocs.org (according to their log it's Sphinx version 1.8.5, and probably Python 2.7 since it's launched with `python` rather than `python3`).

The difference is in the results from the following file, `Shady.Text.rst`, which contains no more than:

```
Shady.Text Sub-module
=====================

.. automodule:: Shady.Text
```

Now, this sub-module happens to contain only a module-level docstring and no member docstrings—that's as intended, so the corresponding html page *should* contain the module docstring and no more.  And this is exactly what happens when I run `make html` locally.  However the result at https://shady.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/Shady.Text.html is content-free (header only, no module docstring).

FWIW my autodoc-related entries in `conf.py` are:

```
autoclass_content = 'both'
autodoc_member_order = 'groupwise'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Check the [build log](https://readthedocs.org/api/v2/build/9098417.txt) for these warnings `WARNING: autodoc: failed to import module u'Text' from module u'Shady'; the module executes module level statement and it might call sys.exit().
WARNING: autodoc: failed to import module u'Video' from module u'Shady'; the module executes module level statement and it might call sys.exit().
looking for now-outdated files... none found`. Most likely, you do not tell RTD to install your package. See https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#my-project-isn-t-building-with-autodoc

Comment: @StevePiercy thanks, that put me on the right track (see answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @StevePiercy for drawing my attention to the crucial lines in the raw log file:

```
WARNING: autodoc: failed to import module u'Text' from module u'Shady'; the module executes module level statement and it might call sys.exit().
WARNING: autodoc: failed to import module u'Video' from module u'Shady'; the module executes module level statement and it might call sys.exit().
```

(I had searched the 9000-line log file for `.Text`, because `Text` on its creates too many hits, but it hadn't occurred to me to search it for `'Text'` in quotes).

To me, the message is misleading: the problem is not that "the module executes module level statements" because that *per se* is allowed.  I wasted some time after noting that *some* module-level statements seemed to be allowed in other sub-modules, and tried to bundle the offending module-level statements into a class decorator thinking maybe sphinx's mysterious module-level-statement-detector would miss them then...)

No, the problem is that not the fact that the module-level statements exist and **might** call `sys.exit()`, but the fact that they **did** indirectly call `sys.exit()` during sphinx's compilation procedure.  This was a quirk of the way I handle missing dependencies, which should probably be re-thought, but I could work around it for now by avoiding my `sys.exit()` call when `os.environ.get('READTHEDOCS')` is truthy.